# How to control a procedural texture with an empty?

Tags: procedural, texture-coordinates

I´d like to -somehow- assign an empty object to drive a procedural texture. The idea is that I can rotate, scale or move the empty and thus it transform the procedural texture (bricks, noise texture, etc..)

How can I manipulate a procedural texture using the position of an empty?
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: try with the Object output of the Texture Coordinate, maybe you'll get what you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an object's visibility controlled by another object or an empty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79851/make-an-objects-visibility-controlled-by-another-object-or-an-empty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @moonboots has commented, you've already got it.. and just done a bit too much?
This setup puts the texture into the Empty's object space, so transforms on the Empty will transform the texture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is often helpful to debug the procedural node coordinates with a setup like [image: this]

As x,y,z get mapped into rgb. Here you can visualize the difference between all the different coordinate outputs, as well as check the correct transformation. As moonboots pointed out, the "Object" output works best for what you are trying to achieve.