# show object in specific area of other object

Tags: modeling, shaders, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to get a specific result like one object should be only visible in front of other object or in area of that other object

[image]

I want to show that first object with image texture should be only visible in other object area.

Thank you

Comment: See this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294408/60759. You would need to use Refraction BSDF plane and transmission depth and mix regular material with transparent since if the object has transparency in it, it will start displaying it's own blackfaces if you try to hide it behind a transparent plane that way...